# How to take a 1's complement of a binary String

Tags: java, string

I have a String of length >10^4 which has only binary numbers.

How can I take 1's complement of it ?

Example-  `Sting a = "0101"`

I want `String b = "1010"`

Is there any better method other than replacing every character using `StringBuffer/StringBuilder`?

Comment: ***Will Sting b = ~a Works?*** you don need to drop a question here to find out that, dont you think?

Comment: What do you mean by "BETTER"?

Comment: Generally we replace character using StringBuffer i.e "1" is replaced with "0" and vice-versa.....So without using that method is there any other method?

Comment: You could parse the binary string to int, _then_ do `~`, and then write back to binary string, but the result will probably not be what you expected (there are many more `0` in the int than were in the string)

Comment: my length of string is around 10^3

Comment: 'Binary `String`' is already a contradiction in terms, and there is no binary string here, only an ASCII representation of binary digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to avoid reinventing the wheel you use `BigInteger`. It’s `not` method gives you almost what you want, only it gives you a negative number when applied to a positive one. To get back into positive, add 2^n where n is the length of the original string:

```
    String a = "0101";
    BigInteger twoToLength = new BigInteger("2").pow(a.length());
    String b = twoToLength.add(new BigInteger(a, 2).not()).toString(2);
    System.out.println(b);
```

This prints:

```
1010
```

The argument `2` to the constructor and `toString()` is an radix indicating binary numbers.

We are not quite there yet: if the original string has leading ones, the leading zeroes in the result are not printed. You will have to prepend these manually to get the same string length as you had originally. I think the easiest way to do this is to add 2^(n+1) instead of 2^n so we are sure there is at least one 1 bit in front of the bits we really care about. So we remove this bit only after converting back to a string:

```
    String a = "0101";
    int length = a.length();
    // add a couple of more bits in front to make sure we have a positive number
    BigInteger twoToLengthPlus1 = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(length + 1);
    String b = twoToLengthPlus1.add(new BigInteger(a, 2).not()).toString(2);
    // remove extra bits from the front again
    b = b.substring(b.length() - length);
```

With this change `1010` becomes `0101`.

Comment: For an input length of 10^4 this will probably perform miserably both time and memory-wise. But it would be interesting to actually try out and measure the results.

Comment: 6 milliseconds on my computer. With no warming-up. @Axel

Comment: @Axel, in comparison your solution uses 2 milliseconds, including a final call to `toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a String? If a [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) is enough, you can do this:

```
public class BinaryComplementCharSequence implements CharSequence {

    private final String source;

    public BinaryComplementCharSequence(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return source.length();
    }

    @Override
    public char charAt(int index) {
        switch (source.charAt(index)) {
        case '0':
            return '1';
        case '1':
            return '0';
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        return new BinaryComplementCharSequence(source.substring(start, end));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder(length()).append(this).toString();
    }

}
```

If you really need a `String`, call `toString()` (but that uses a StringBuilder again).

Answer (score 0):

You've already figured it out: use a `StringBuilder` and replace every bloody char individually.

You could also use a char array: `char ca[] = str.toCharArray()` to extract the characters, modify individual chars in `ca`, `String newstr =new String(ca)` to pack the array back into a `String`.  Might be slightly faster.

Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

Every char check with '1' and invert:

```
char[] charsConverted = new char[a.length()];
    char[] charArray = a.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        boolean b = charArray[i] == '1';
        charsConverted[i] = !b ? '1' : '0';
    }
    String b= String.valueOf(charsConverted);
```